# Mapping Evil-Ex-Command to "ei" in Emacs

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In Emacs evil-mode, I'm trying to bind the string "ei" to an ex command that opens up my init file. This is what I came up with:

```
(defun edit-init () (find-file "~/.emacs"))
(evil-ex-define-cmd "ei" 'edit-init)
```

When I try to run the ex command (using ":ei"), Emacs tells me "Unknown command "ei").

I checked the evil-ex-commands variable and the new command is correctly being stored in the list. It looks like this:

```
("ei" . edit-init)
```

My first thought was that the default ex command of "e" for edit was interfering with the command somehow, however I tried binding "ew" to other-window and it worked fine.

Am I missing something about how evil-ex commands are created? Is there a limitation on what characters can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a command, not just a function. In other words, your command is missing an `(interactive)` clause:

```
(defun edit-init ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/.emacs"))
```